# OpenFileDialog showing different files depending on if build for 32-bit or 64-bit architecture

Tags: .net, vb.net, openfiledialog

I have noticed `OpenFileDialog` failing to show all files in a directory, this happens in **my** application but also **other** windows native programs such as Task Manager "New Task" "Browse" option (which uses the `OpenFileDialog` Control), does anyone know the reason and possible workarounds for that?
Even running Task Manager as admin didn't fix it so its not caused by privileges it seems

**Edit:** i now know this was caused by a appcompat feature called [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) apparently i was starting Task Manager 32bit, aswell as my own application and hence it was showing me the 32bit system32 aka SysWOW64 folder (talk about wierd naming schemes, on Windows 7 64bit System32 has the 64bit files and SysWOW64 holds the 32bit files) and it seems that when you are running a 32bit build of a certain application you have no access to the 64bit System32 folder via `OpenFileDialog` whatsoever.

As example, seen here, its missing SnippingTool.exe (but its not just limited to)

[image: TaskManager OpenFileDialog]
While i am certain it does exist at the target location
[image: Windows Explorer]

Comment: I was more or less surprised with the behaviour described on this question. My surprise grew further after reading Hans Passant's answer. But the most surprising thing is that this question has already got 3 votes to be closed because of being off-topic!! Lots of highly knowledgeable people here (for whom all this is evident or who can ask this in a much better way). IMO, the question is pretty good and the answer is excellent.

Comment: @varocarbas hehe, yeah i did try to make the question as clear as possible since it was such a odd one, as for those people voting as off-topic they must have never ran into this quirk/oddity.

Comment: Well... everyone runs into weird/difficult things; but quite a few people prefer to look in a different direction (to the guy who will solve it :)). I would like to see this question put on hold (no big deal for you: just change a bit the description and will be able to reopen it), to know who were the close-voters. I seriously cannot come up with a better way to ask this question.

Comment: "You may be able to get help on Super User" -> completely pointless statement. I don't think that there are too many programmers knowing how to solve this problem (before this question). One thing is knowing the duplicity 32/64 folders and a completely different story is knowing that System.IO follows the shown rules blindly; I didn't have any idea of that and do consider this question/answer really useful.

Comment: @varocarbas i agree, this is a programming specific question and because i didn't find the question being asked on SO i had to ask it (google also was of no use) lets hope the moderators see it for what it is since i can't see how it could be seen as off-topic.

Comment: Well, I got that off-topic vote wrong.  Sorry.  All I can do is to vote to re-open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens when you run your code on the 64-bit version of Windows.  The navigation bar says that you are looking at c:\windows\system32.  But you actually *see* the content of c:\windows\syswow64.  The same thing happens when you navigate to c:\program files.  You'll actually see the content of c:\program files (x86).  There is no 32-bit version of SnippingTool.exe so it is missing from the list.

This is an appcompat feature called ["File system redirection"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Designed to give 32-bit programs a fighting chance to survive on a 64-bit operating system.

You turn it off by allowing your program to run as a 64-bit process.  Right-click your EXE project, Properties, Build tab.  Change the Platform target setting to AnyCPU.  On VS2012 and up, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" option.

Comment: Wow!! Answer deserving +10; unfortunately, I can only give +1 :)

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick nicely, i vaguely knew about this "feature" but not what its consequences were exactly, good to know!

Comment: Note if you ***need*** to be 32 bit (say you are working with a 3rd party dll that does not have a 64 bit version) you can access the 64 bit `system32` folder from a 32bit program by going to `%windir%\sysnative`